# .NET create JSON object, where value contains quotes

Tags: javascript, .net, json

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` to generate JSON object:

```
JObject testObject = new JObject();
testObject["key"] = "\"value\"";
var result = testObject.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Result of this operation is: `{ "key": "\"value\"" }`

But, when I try parse it using JS:

```
var data = JSON.parse( '{ "key": "\"value\"" }' );
```

I am getting error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 11`

If I manually change json to: `{ "key": "\\"value\\"" }`, it parses it correctly. However, i can not generate it from .NET.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't have to do any manual escaping.. What if you do `testObject["key"] = '"value"';`? I don't know anything about newtonSoft but serializers in all other languages take care of escaping

Comment: Why are you doing `testObject["key"] = "\"value\"";` instead of `testObject["key"] = "value";`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz clearly states why in title... OP wants quoted text

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz in just an example, basically value is a string, which contains quotes in it, example: "before quotes \"between quotes\" after quotes"

Comment: @charlietfl `testObject["key"] = '"value"';` isn't valid C#. But the problem isn't with Newtonsoft. The problem is that OP tried to copy the JSON over to JavaScript by hand and did so incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

What you're missing is that you tried to copy your JSON into a JavaScript string literal, but you didn't correctly escape it.

If you want to put the JSON `{ "key": "\"value\"" }` into a string literal, this value contains backslashes, so you would have to escape them:

```
var data = JSON.parse( '{ "key": "\\"value\\"" }' );
```

This is exactly what you found to work correctly.

If you try to run the line you had:

```
var data = JSON.parse( '{ "key": "\"value\"" }' );
```

That string literal evaluates to the value `{ "key": ""value"" }`, which is not the same as the JSON that Newtonsoft produced and is not valid JSON.

**The bottom line:** It looks like you've generated some valid JSON with a library, but then you tried to copy it by hand and created an error in the process of doing so. Perhaps this was just for experimentation, but you should set up a pathway for the JSON to pass from Newtonsoft to your JavaScript without human intervention. This should prevent such issues like the one you had.